# How to check roles or permissions on AWS AppSync OIDC directive at the Graphql schema level

Tags: graphql, openid-connect, auth0, directive, aws-appsync

I am in the process of transitioning from `Cognito` to `Auth0`. For some of my `AppSync` queries and mutations, I have applied the @aws_auth directive, which can include a list of `Cognito` groups to control the level of access.

The example below displays a mutation, called `createEvent`, which only allows users who are in the `Cognito` groups, tracker_admin and pilot_admin, to execute this mutation.

Here is an example:

```
createEvent(input: CreateEventInput!): Event
    @aws_auth(cognito_groups:["tracker_admin", "pilot_admin"])
```

I have successfully configured an additional authentication provider (`OPENID_CONNECT`) with `Auth0` and added the directive `@aws_oidc` to my `GraphQL` schema. In my `Auth0` dashboard I have set up scopes which get added to the user's access token based on their roles when they authenticate with my application client.

My goal is to update my schema to use the OIDC authentication and to apply  permissions to the directive like so:

```
directive @aws_oidc(
    permissions: [String]
) on OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION

createEvent(input: CreateEventInput!): Event
    @aws_oidc(permissions:["create:event"])
```

My `Auth0` access_token does have a `"permissions"` field which includes a list of the scopes that the user has. These list of permissions come into my lambda resolver in the event context in the `"identity"` under the `"claims"`.

How can I accomplish this authorization at the schema level with a directive for `@aws_oidc` just like I currently have with the `@aws_auth` for User Pool Cognito Groups?

Answer (score 0):

This is way late, but for anyone else who needs help setting up AppSync with OIDC, I came up with this after looking at this blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/graphql-security-appsync-amplify/ . Below is a sample of how to set this up in your `schema.graphql`

Change the value of `groups` to be w/e you need, and `groupClaim` to be the claim on your OIDC token to read. Tailor the operations as needed.

**Note:** The example below is specifically when using @aws-amplify only.

```
type Foo
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      {
        allow: groups
        groups: ["ADMIN", "USER"]
        operations: [create, update, delete, read]
        provider: oidc
        groupClaim: "role"
      }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  anotherId: ID!
}
```

Comment: If I try to add this in AppSync' schema in AWS console I get "internal failure" error... anyone seen that? (copied/pasted above Foo type)